# can't get pytesseract and cv2 to accurately OCR a screenshot from a phone (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I am currently looking at making a function that reads a screenshot taken from wordle, and produces a list of the possible words. I am struggling to understand why I am not able to get an accurate OCR using CV2 and pytesseract.
My first attempt (no pre-processing):

[example wordle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L8Ef.jpg)

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Pictures\attemp1.jpeg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

**output**

```
11:29 a 4G

=@® #£Wordle dh %

DanwE
Ptalijn|r

aA @nytimes.com @ i

Cc oo gf og Oo
```

In my second attempt I wanted to see if I could use some pre-processing to at least get **some** of the letters correct (shamelessly stolen from another post):

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Pictures\attemp1.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph open to remove noise and invert image
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening

# Perform text extraction
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 3')
print(data)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**output**

```
11:29 o 46@

=@® Wordle &%

a Oi

° 7 oi , ie ‘ ° ° Bi
B oi ° ‘ ° oi .
ENTER Z x c Vv

AA w nytimes.com @

< ho mom ©
```

I feel like the OCR is trying to turn everything into a word instead of treating each characters as its own 'word' however I was unable to find any config options that allowed for this condition.

In a perfect world I would be able to return a nested list with character, position, colour. though I am just struggling with accuracy at this point. This is my first 'computer vision' task so I apologise if I have overlooked something simple.
Thank you

Comment: Simple pipeline: Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold, find contours, sort contours from left to right, filter using contour threshold area + approximate square contour, extract individual ROI, then finally OCR each square ROI. To get your detailed nested list information, in each ROI, you can find 1) average mean for the color, 2) OCR for the letter/character, and 3) centroid for the coordinate